# PHP website using Docker and Nginx with subdomains on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, nginx, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

Let's say i own the domain `domain.com`. I want to host, on my Raspberry Pi 4, a PHP website when I go on the URL `domain.com`, in parallel with a NextCloud instance when I go to `drive.domain.com`.

For this purpose I use Docker and Nginx following this tutorial https://linuxhandbook.com/nginx-reverse-proxy-docker/#step-5-run-other-service-containers-with-reverse-proxy where we setup a VIRTUAL_HOST for each subdomain on the network `net`. I managed to get the Nextcloud instance working on my subdomain `drive.domain.com`.

When I try the `nginx-dummy` example using `docker run --rm --name nginx-dummy -e VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST=domain.com -e VIRTUAL_PORT=80 --network net -d nginx:latest`, it seems to work because the url `domain.com` lands the nginx config page. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to change this html page into my PHP website and get it working on `domain.com`. Folder being like so:

[image]

I tried to create a `docker-compose.yml` with Nginx and PHP like so:

```
version: '3'
services:
 # Nginx server configuration
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: 'domain.com'
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
    depends_on:
      - php
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./webcontent:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
 # Php-fpm configuration
  php:
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./webcontent:/var/www/html
      - ./php:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

but it did not work, returning `502 Bad Gateway`.

Also, Let's encrypt certificates don't seem to be working. Maybe for another question though.

Would you have an idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

After trying several things I found the best solution for my needs. The **linuxserver** team did an incredible job available here https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag#docker-compose.

Their SWAG container setup is easy to follow and really well explained, from setting up a webserver, SSL certificates, and NextCloud in parallel seemlessly. Just a piece of art.